# hd images not working

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In simulation and on device, there is something that happen with my cocos2d which its strange.
I have xcode 4.2, running on simulation ios5 and have `cocos2d v1.0.1` .

The app is working great, when all images in HD mode(double size),but without the `-hd`
Then when i have tried to change all images from `image.png` to `image-hd.png`, he cant find the image anymore.

I have to say that after i added the `-hd` ,and **before** i have cleaned the cache it worked.
After the cache was clean, it stopped.

The HD is enabled in my delegate, and it worked in the past as well.

he somehow cant except anymore the HD images.

any idea ??
thanks.

Comment: Are you testing on a device or in the simulator?  Have you made sure to add the -hd images to your project by dragging them in?  It's not enough to just add them to the Resources folder (unless you're using folder references)

Comment: Sorry, I see that you're in the simulator.  Are you replacing the non-hd images? (don't, leave both).  Are you using the retina simulator? (by default the iPhone4 looking simulator isn't retina)

Comment: @ Austin Fitzpatrick thanks. IN xcode , i am going to my assets, and change each image to image-hd. in the project folder i have checked and it changed too . i have already drag them before the -hd.

Comment: The HD elements aren't supposed to be the only ones in the project.  If you're developing for iPhone with Retina display support you should have two copies of each image, one with "-hd" and one without.

If you're developing for iPhone and iPad you'll likely have 3 or 4 versions of each image.  One normal, one with "-hd", "-ipad", and "-ipadhd".

Comment: Also, in the simulator, ensure that you're actually using a Retina simulator (Hardware -> Device -> iPhone (retina))

Comment: thanks a lot i know that. i have number of apps at the store. the simulation is in retina, and my device also retina. the hd should work isnt it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was something that drove me crazy when I updated to v1.0.1. I spent hours trying to understand why it would work sometimes and not other times between projects. Basically all you need to do is make sure that you include the different images named properly in your project. You can't have just the image-hd.png in your project alone or it will fail. You have to include both the image.png and the image-hd.png in your project or it will error as you described. Once you have both or if you're doing both iPhone and iPad, include all 4 types. (image.png, image-hd.png, image-ipad.png, and image-ipadhd.png)

Then in your code only reference the image.png and v1.0.1 will do the rest.